# Bigcommerce API network error

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I've been using Bigcommerce API for over a year now to run batch programs and today suddenly it stopped working with the errors shown below.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message
>    'error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure' in C:\Dropbox\Looma's\Software\Prod\Order Manager - Retail\Download_Retail_Orders\bigcommerce.php:82
>   Stack trace:
>   0 C:\Dropbox\Looma's\Software\Prod\Order Manager - Retail\Download_Retail_Orders\bigcommerce.php(142): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->handleResponse()
>
> 1. C:\Dropbox\Looma's\Software\Prod\Order Manager - Retail\Download_Retail_Orders\bigcommerce.php(343): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->get('https://store-1...')
> 2. C:\Dropbox\Looma's\Software\Prod\Order Manager - Retail\Download_Retail_Orders\bigcommerce.php(544): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getCount('/orders/count')
> 3. C:\Dropbox\Looma's\Software\Prod\Order Manager - Retail\Download_Retail_Orders\index.php(140): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getOrdersCount()
> 4. {main}  thrown in C:\Dropbox\Looma's\Software\Prod\Order Manager - Retail\Download_Retail_Orders\bigcommerce.php on line 82

Any ideas on where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

From BigCommerce...
Thank you for contacting Bigcommerce API support and allowing us time to look over your concern. The problem you are seeing is due to the recent deprecation of the RC4 cipher suite (please go to developer.bigcommerce.com to see the banner we posted regarding this). This is a PCI requirement change that needed to be done and we are now doing it globally to all Bigcommerce IP addresses. It is likely that your client libraries is making a specific call to use cipher. You will either need to modify the library/ scripts to not make these references or update to the latest client libraries available at https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/clients . Please let us know if there is anything else we can do to help related ot this case. As always, please don't hesitate to contact us if there any other API questions or issues you may have.